# copying rows with checked checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to consolidate rows with checked checkboxes from three sheets (“Liver”, ”Lung” and “Kidney”)  into one sheet "Report". I would like to grab rows that do not contain word "sample" in column A.  When I paste the data into "Report" I would like to label each group of rows with the corresponding originating sheet name by adding a row in between that contains the sheet name, in column A.

I came up with this code which goes into an infinite loop and I have to kill Excel to stop it. This is just for "Lung" sheet only but I'm hoping to reproduce it for the other two sheets. 
Ideally, I would like to use arrays to transfer the data but I'm not sure how to work it out.  Any suggestions on how to fix what I already have or to improve it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

```
For Each chkbx In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes

 If chkbx.Value = 1 Then
    For r = 2 To Rows.count
         If Cells(r, 1).Top = chkbx.Top And InStr(Cells(r, 1).Value, "Sample") < 0 Then
         '
           With Worksheets("Report")
              LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("A" & LRow & ":P" & LRow) = _
             Worksheets("Lung").Range("A" & r & ":P" & r).Value
         End With
           Exit For
       End If
     Next r
   End If
 Next
```

Comment: The (seemingly) infinite loop is caused by `For r = 2 To Rows.count` which would eventually end after all 1 million+ rows on the sheet; you can fix it by determining the last used row on the sheet with boxes. Array would be much faster and quite simple to use (once you get used to them) but in your case there is a need to process CheckBoxes and interact with every row

Comment: Very crude but you could switch to `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count`.  There are a number of reasons to not do this, but it will at least quit before it reaches the end of the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code bellow will generate the following reports (details bellow):

[image: result]

.

There are 3 sections, but all code should be pasted into one user module:

.

Subs to execute:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const REPORT    As String = "Report_"
Private Const EXCLUDE   As String = "Sample"
Private Const L_COL     As String = "P"

Private wsRep As Worksheet
Private lRowR As Long

Public Sub updateSet1()
    updateSet 1
End Sub
Public Sub updateSet2()
    updateSet 2
End Sub
Public Sub updateSet3()
    updateSet 3
End Sub

Public Sub updateSet(ByVal id As Byte)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    showSet id
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Sub consolidateAllSheets()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook
        consolidateReport .Worksheets("COLON"), True  'time stamp to 1st line of report
        consolidateReport .Worksheets("LUNG")
        consolidateReport .Worksheets("MELANOMA")
        wsRep.Rows(lRowR).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

.

**showSet**() - use **1 for Set1**, **2 for Set2**, **3 for Set2 edited**:

```
Public Sub showSet(ByVal id As Byte)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cb As Shape, lft As Double, mid As Double, thisWs As Worksheet
    Dim lRed As Long, lBlu As Long, cn As String, cbo As Object, s1 As Boolean

    If id <> 1 And id <> 2 And id <> 3 Then Exit Sub

    lRed = RGB(255, 155, 155): lBlu = RGB(155, 155, 255)
    Set thisWs = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, REPORT, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            lft = ws.Cells(1, 2).Left
            mid = lft + ((ws.Cells(1, 2).Width / 2) - 5)
            For Each cb In ws.Shapes
                cn = cb.Name
                Set cbo = cb.OLEFormat.Object
                s1 = InStr(1, cn, "set1", 1) > 0
                If id < 3 Then
                    cb.Visible = IIf(s1, (id = 1), (id <> 1))
                    cb.Left = IIf(cb.Visible, mid, lft)
                    cbo.Interior.Color = IIf(s1, lBlu, lRed)
                Else
                    cb.Visible = True
                    cb.Left = IIf(s1, lft + 3, mid + 6.5)
                    cbo.Interior.Color = IIf(s1, lBlu, lRed)
                End If: ws.Activate
                With cbo
                    .Width = 15
                    .Height = 15
                End With
            Next
        Else
            ws.Visible = IIf((id = 3), -1, IIf(InStr(1, ws.Name, id) = 0, 0, -1))
        End If
    Next
    thisWs.Activate   'to properly update checkbox visibility
End Sub
```

.

**consolidateReport**()

```
Public Sub consolidateReport(ByRef ws As Worksheet, Optional dt As Boolean = False)
    Dim fRowR As Long, vSetID As Byte, vSetName As String
    Dim lRow As Long, thisRow As Long, cb As Variant

    vSetID = IIf(ws.Shapes("cbSet2_03").Visible, 2, 1)
    vSetName = "Set" & vSetID
    Set wsRep = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(REPORT & vSetID)
    fRowR = wsRep.Range("A" & wsRep.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        With ws
            lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
            lRowR = fRowR + 1
            With wsRep.Cells(lRowR, 1)
                .Value2 = ws.name
                .Interior.Color = vbYellow
                If dt Then .Offset(0, 2) = Format(Now, "mmm dd yyyy, hh:mm AMPM")
            End With
            For Each cb In .Shapes
                If InStr(1, cb.name, vSetName, 0) Then
                    If cb.OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
                        thisRow = cb.TopLeftCell.Row
                        If InStr(1, .Cells(thisRow, 1).Value2, EXCLUDE, 1) = 0 Then
                            lRowR = lRowR + 1
                            wsRep.Range("A" & lRowR & ":" & L_COL & lRowR).Value2 = _
                                .Range("A" & thisRow & ":" & L_COL & thisRow).Value2
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If fRowR = lRowR - 1 Then
                wsRep.Cells(lRowR, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                lRowR = lRowR - 1
                MsgBox "No checkboxes checked for sheet " & ws.name
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

.

The process starts with one file, expected to have 2 sets of checkboxes on each sheet (column 2):

- cbSet1_01, cbSet1_02, cbSet1_03...
- cbSet2_01, cbSet2_02, cbSet2_03...

as in this image

[image]

(check-box colors will be reset by code as long as they follow the naming convention above)

.

1. Generate two files, one for Set1, the other for Set2 by running **`Sub updateSet()`**

   - **`showSet 1`** hides Set2 (Report_2 and all checkboxes, on all sheets) - Save File1
   - **`showSet 2`** hides Set1 (Report_1 and all checkboxes, on all sheets) - Save File2
2. Distribute, then retrieve the updated files

   - Open File1 and run **`Sub consolidateAllSheets()`** to generate Report_1
   - Open File2 and run **`Sub consolidateAllSheets()`** to generate Report_2

     Compare Report_1 to Report_2
3. Generate Set 2 for editing by running **`Sub updateSet()`**

   - **`showSet 3`** shows Set1 and Set2 (all checkboxes, and both reports) - Save File3

     Compare File1, File2, and File3

Comment: Paul, this is great!!! One more question:Two different people will analyze the data independently and their results will be compared, therefore, I would like two have two columns with checkboxes, “A” and “B”.   The first analyst will check boxes in column “A” and the second in column “B”.  Is it possible to specify in the code which column of checkboxes is being evaluated? This way I could make a separate report for each analyst.  I’m not sure if this is even possible, but would be awesome! Thanks

Comment: I plan on hiding either column "A" or "B", depending on which analyst is looking at the Workbook.  We don’t want each analyst to see each other’s check boxes.

Comment: I think I understand what you want to do: add 2 more columns between Col 1 and Col 2 on all sheets, and each new column will hold a separate set of checkboxes. File for person 1 will hide second set, file for person 2 will hide the first set. If that's the case it's quite simple to do, if naming convention for the checkboxes will be similar to: all objects in set 1 will be named cbSet1_01, cbSet1_02, cbSet1_03, and set 2: cbSet2_01, cbSet2_02, cbSet2_03... Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but I plan to use the same Workbook for both analysts.  After the first analyst has checked the checkboxes in Col 1 he will make a report and hide Col 1 so the second analyst can't see it. Does this make sense? When I created the checkboxes I didn't assign  names to them. I did this `ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(CLeft, CTop, CWidth, CHeight).Select`

Comment: `With Selection
            .Caption = ""
            .Value = xlOff
            .Display3DShading = False
        End With`

Comment: I think I need two macros Analyst1_Report and Analyst2_Report. Analyst1_Report will only acknowledge checkboxes in Col1 and Analyst2_Report checkboxes in Col2

Comment: Working on it, but I'm modifying it based on checkbox names cbSet1 and cbSet2 (and it will generate 2 Report sheets - I'll give you more details when I update the answer)

Comment: Thank You! I really like the idea of placing both sets of checkboxes in the same column and using color coding.  The consolidateReport logic is based on which set of checkboxes is hidden and that is great!   I need to figure out how to include an option of revealing/hiding the first set of checkboxes in File2 so that the results of the two reviewers could be evaluated by the third party by comparing the two sets checkboxes.  If the third party makes any changes to the second set of checkboxes they would continue by hiding the first set of checkboxes again and generating a report from File2.

Comment: I updated the code so now it can show all checkboxes and both reports if you want, or you could simply keep set2 in file2 visible for the third party, but if another report is generated for set2 it will be appended after the first report. The appended reports will be distinct by having a date-time stamp next to the first sheet in the report (Liver), and a thicker line between reports

Comment: Could you please explain the meaning behind the following line of code `ws.Visible = IIf((id = 3), -1, IIf(InStr(1, ws.Name, id) = 0, 0, -1))` I'm trying to find the place where you split the file into two copies but I can't find it. Thanks again, this is really great!

Comment: The line has 2 nested Ifs: it hides or shows the report sheets based on id: _If id = 3 then Report_1 and Report_2 are visible, Else: If sheet name (Report_1 or Report_2) contains the id (1 or 2), make it visible, Else hide it_. In my test file I have 5 sheets: Liver, Lung, Kidney, Report_1, and Report_2. Splitting the file is manual: for Set1, hides all checkboxes in Set2 (shows all checkboxes in Set1), and hides Report_2 (unhides Report_1) - SaveAs File1. Then change it for Set2: hides all checkboxes in Set1 (shows all checkboxes in Set2), and hides Report_1 (unhides Report_2) - SaveAs File2

Comment: I get "Object doesn't support this property or method" error on this line `Set cbCol = cb.OLEFormat.Object.Object` in Showset. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83333/discussion-between-paul-bica-and-user3781528).