# Check boxes are deleted when a workbook is saved

Tags: excel, vba

Column B contains checkboxes.  My data organized in table format.  I've noticed if I filter the data and then close and save the file, the checkboxes from rows that were hidden are deleted.  I've added a routine that removes the filters from all worksheets before the workbook is closed but it still deletes the checkboxes. It appears that the checkboxes are deleted when the workbook is saved.  Please help fix this problem.

Thank you

Code I used to remove the filter (removeAllFilters)

```
If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then
  ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

The sub is called in the Workbook_beforeClose

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Call removeAllFilters
    Application.OnKey "^m"

End Sub
```

Comment: It only happens when a filter is left on... What should I do?

Comment: if I remove the filter manually or with code before I click on Exit file it works fine...but I can't rely on the user to remember to remove the filter because I know they will forget and I will be in trouble.

Comment: Ah, I see, I was filtering then turning off the filter and the darn things disappear.

Comment: @user3781528 had a similar problem with checkboxes and Dropdownlists: Those Controls aren't deleted - they still exist - but their dimensions are 0 when the control is on a cell which is hidden. As soon as you close the workbook the control will save those dimension and won't be relocated when opening the workbook again. my workaround was to unfilter the data before close and save the filter information. On the Workbook open event i set the filter again, everything worked fine afterwards - no problems since then.

Comment: It's starting to make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being related to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31374719/4914662), the check boxes are not deleted when you close the file:

- when using the Autofilter the boxes are moved with the hidden rows (on top of each other)

To solve the issue make the following changes:

.

Replace the code in **ThisWorkbook** with this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "^m", "LoadForm"
    setSheets
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.OnKey "^m"
    removeAutoFilter
    ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

---

.

In VBA module **modReport** add 2 Subs:

```
Public Sub removeAutoFilter()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Range, cRow As Long, thisWs As Worksheet, cbN As String
    Dim l As Double, r As Double, aSet As Byte, s1 As Boolean, s2 As Boolean
    Dim tbl As ListObject, done As Boolean, isUsed As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: setSheets

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = wsColon.Name Or ws.Name = wsLung.Name Or ws.Name = wsMela.Name Then
            If Not ws.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
                For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
                    tbl.Range.AutoFilter: tbl.Range.AutoFilter: done = True
                Next
                If Not done Then ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter: ws.UsedRange.AutoFilter
            End If
            For Each lRow In ws.UsedRange.Rows
                With lRow
                    cRow = .Row:  isUsed = Len(.Cells(1, EMPTY_ROW_CHECK_3).Value2) > 0
                    If (cRow > 2 And isUsed) Or (cRow > 2 And .Cells(1, 3).Value > 0) Then
                        getAlignment .Cells(1, 2), l, r
                        cbN = IIf(cRow < 10, "_0" & cRow, "_" & cRow)
                        If cRow = 3 Then
                            s1 = ws.CheckBoxes("cb" & SET_Name1 & 1 & cbN).Visible
                            s2 = ws.CheckBoxes("cb" & SET_Name1 & 2 & cbN).Visible
                            aSet = IIf(s1, IIf(s2, 3, 1), 2)
                        End If
                        restCB ws, "cb" & SET_Name1 & 1 & cbN, .Top, l - 1
                        restCB ws, "cb" & SET_Name1 & 2 & cbN, .Top, r + 7
                    End If
                End With
            Next
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    updateSet aSet
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub restCB(ByRef ws As Worksheet, cbN As String, t As Double, l As Double)
    Dim cb As Shape
    For Each cb In ws.Shapes
        With cb
            If .Name = cbN Then
                .Visible = True
                .Top = t
                .Left = l
                Exit For
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

---

- It removes any filter on all sheets, and resets data to AutoFiltered
- Determines the active set (1, 2, or 3)
- Un-hides all check boxes (both sets)
- Realigns them vertically, and horizontally based on current row
- Re-initializes active set
- Saves file before closing

Comment: Thanks, I get an error (Run-time error '1004' Select Method of Range Class failed) on line `ws.Cells(1, 1).Select` of removeAutoFilter sub.

Comment: Paul, If you remove all checkboxes and add them back before the Workbook closes what will happen to the True/False designation in column B?

Comment: I updated it with a new solution that preserves the True\False values of all check boxes

Comment: which version of addAllCheckboxes should I use old/new?  I don't think I need removeAllCheckboxes sub any longer, correct? Thanks, I will test tomorrow morning.

Comment: The addAllCheckboxes and removeAllCheckboxes are not needed anymore (there are no significant changes between old and new other than calling them for cleanup). You can still call them individually if you need to reset all objects

Answer (score 0):

When I Showed all data, then Turn off autofilter the textboxes seem to go back into place, I do see this has been an issue for a while. This worked for me Showing all data then Turning off filter. There may have to be some error checking as well.

```
With ActiveSheet
    If .AutoFilterMode = True Then
        .ShowAllData
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
End With
```

Comment: How is it different from `If (ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode And` `ActiveSheet.FilterMode) Or ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then`
  `ActiveSheet.ShowAllData` ?

Comment: Did you call this code from Workbook_BeforeClose?  Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I've tried calling your code from Workbook_BeforeClose without any luck.